# Sharing internal classes/methods/etc. between Swift modules

Tags: swift, module, frameworks

I have 2 Swift modules, let's call them module 'A' and module 'B'. I need to share some code between these modules, let's call this module 'Core'.

These modules are used by customer applications.  Customers use either module A, module B, or both and they always get a copy of 'Core'.  Module 'Core' contains a data model that is used by both 'A' and 'B', and exposed to the customer. However, I want 'A' and 'B' to be able to use internal methods/classes/etc. in 'Core' and not expose these to the customer (that is, I don't want to make them public). For example, I want 'A' and 'B' to be able to create instances of the data model I defined in 'Core' but I don't want the customer to be able to instantiate them.

In short, I want modules 'A' and 'B' to be able to access 'Core' as if it was part of the same module. What I'm looking for is the equivalent of a 'friend class' in C++, but for modules in Swift.

I could, of course, put everything into a huge project and then use different build targets to create A+Core, B+Core and A+B+Core modules, but that would lead to a combinatorial explosion once we add modules C, D, E, F, etc.

This seems like a very common way to organise code, but I can't seem to figure out a way to do this in Swift 4. Has anyone here found a way to do this or another way of structuring their codebase so that private code can be shared between modules ?

Answer (score 0):

Friend classes in C++ have nothing to do with modules.
The normal solution to this issue would be to create module C, and have A and B use it internally.

Comment: I used the 'friend class' as an example of similar functionality (giving private access to a different class, or in this case module. I would like to classify A and B as 'friend modules' of C , so they can access members with 'internal' access). I cannot create a module C and have A and B use it internally, because A and B cannot access internal members of C, and I cannot make members of C public without making them accessible to the end-user of our libraries.